# HHVM can't find a file

Tags: php, command-line-interface, hhvm

I'm running ZendFramework app from CLI. Everything works good when I run it with PHP. Today I have installed HHVM and I wanted to run my app with it but I got an error:

```
Fatal error: File not found: Zend/Application.php in /home/bartek/Documents/WWW/WOF/scripts/server.php on line 7
```

This is line 7:

```
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
```

Why PHP can find this file and HHVM can't?

Comment: Haven't used HHVM yet but it could be due to the `include_path` in php.ini not being set correctly to include the Zend Framework.

Comment: It was include_path commented out in HHVM php.ini

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution. To not leave this question unanswered could you either accept my answer below (it's basically a copy of my comment) or if you think this question is no longer needed delete it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it was the [`include_path` in php.ini](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) not being configured like it was in your PHP configuration so the Zend Framework could not be included.

If both HHVM and PHP reside on the same system they can still use different php.ini files so both could potentially run with different configurations.